# Practicing mapreduce in hadoop-streaming but getting an error running JAR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, hadoop-streaming

I am quite new to AWS and trying to get hands-on experience with the features.

This is what I am trying to run:

```
hadoop jar
/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar \
-file mapperage.py -mapper 'python mapperage.py' \
-file reduced_max.py -reducer 'python reduced_max.py' \
-input /user/hadoop/CustomerAge.txt \
-output /user/hadoop/output_1
```

This is the particular error it shows:

> -bash: /lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar: permission denied

My Hadoop distribution version is Amazon 2.8.5

Quite new to AWS, not sure what to try.